# Can't fix a 'java.util.NoSuchElement' error

Tags: java, file, loops, random, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to make a program that generate either 'win' or 'lose' for a coin flip, **output** the data into a file, and read that data to calculate the **average**, but I'm getting a '`java.util.NoSuchElementException`' **error**. I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting this.. Help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
public class BottleCapPrize
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {            
        int random;
        int loop = 1;
        double trials = 0;
        double winCounter = 0;
        double average;
        String token = "";

        //

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (new File("MonteCarloMethod.txt"));

        //User Input Trials
        System.out.print("Number of trials: ");
        trials = in.nextInt();

        //For loop (random, and print to file)
        average = 0;
        for(loop = 1; loop <= trials; loop++)
        {
            random = rand.nextInt(5);
            if(random == 1)
            {
                outFile.println("Trial: " + loop + " WIN!");
            }
            outFile.println("Trial: " + loop + " LOSE");
        }

        outFile.close();

        //read output 
        File fileName = new File("MonteCarloMethod.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        while (inFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            token = inFile.next();
            if (token.equalsIgnoreCase( "WIN!" ))
            {
                winCounter++;
            }

        }

        //average and print average
        average = winCounter / trials * 100;
        outFile.println("Average number of caps to win: " + average);
        System.out.println("Average number of caps to win: " + average);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line throwing  `java.util.NoSuchElementException`?

Comment: Can you please include a full stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `inFile.next()` to `inFile.nextLine()`

also, you will want to change `if (token.equalsIgnoreCase( "WIN!" ))` to `if(token.contains("WIN!"))` as otherwise it will never pass (`.equals` check to see if the entire line is "WIN!" and only "WIN!", `.contains` checks to see if the line has "WIN!" in it.)

Comment: Can't believe nobody else noticed the `.equalsIgnoreCase` flaw

Answer (score 0):

In the reading loop you test for `inFile.hasNextLine()`, but try to get the next token by `inFile.next()`. However, having a next line does not necessarily mean that there is a next token.

Either change `hasNextLine()` to `hasNext()`, or change `next()` to `nextLine()` (provided that all tokens are on separate lines).